# Why do people use Messaging when you can use Files and a Batch tool?

Tags: java, architecture, batch-processing, messaging, in-memory-database

We have 2 in-memory java components (a data grid and an olap cube).

We currently use a batch processing tool to load the data grid, and we dynamically create batch jobs when users want to make updates to the data. What I am thinking is we should extend our batch tool so that it also takes responsibility to load data into the olap cube. In terms of the data transfer, the data grid should write out a file, copy it to the server the olap cube runs on, and the olap cube should then read in this file.

The other option we have is when the data grid finishes loading or applying an update, it sends a message to a queue. The olap cube will then read this message, and call a service on the data grid to pull the data in. I am strongly against this option since it is not file based, which means the support team will have trouble understanding it.

So question is, why should we use messaging?

Comment: File based messaging requires you to carefully manage the file lifecycle (including crash recovery).  It sounds like you're already pretty comfortable doing that.  Queue solutions handle the details of persisting the data, and some offer the capability of participating in a transaction.  Good queue solutions provide tools to see what is in the queue, just as you can look at files on disk.

Answer (score 3):

Because if you write your own transaction files, you have to worry about:

- whether the transaction got written to the file
- whether the file got transmitted correctly, completely, or indeed at all.
- whether the file got read completely, and if not where you were up to when you stopped reading

as well as all kinds of reliablity issues concerning the actual media.

Messaging systems do all that for you.